# MVC Application state Lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC you can store values in the Application state by using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["example"] = "test";
```

How is the lifetime of Application state handles. I presume when the App pool recycles it clears. When else does it clear?

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [this page](http://www.wengkien.com/2015/10/20/lifetime-of-static-variable-in-iis/)
there are five reasons why your static datas :

```
The pool decide that need to make a recompile.
You open the app_offline.htm file
You make manual restart of the pool
The pool is reach some limits that you have define and make restart.
For any reason you restart the iis, or the pool.
```